# Email Spamming Issues

Tags: php, email, spam

I'm putting my first website online and i'm having concerns of email spamming. There are sections of the website that has feedback forms (email not displayed), while some other pages have the email displayed. . .

I've heard people talk about email Bots crawling on numerous site and spamming them to death.

Please what do you advice on this issue.

Please pardon me if this place dosent seem to me the best place to ask this quetion. I'm quite new here.

Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Don't put your email address in plain sight. Use captchas

Comment: You can _obfuscate_ email addresses ([search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=email+obfuscation)). It's not fool-proof, but it will get rid of a lot of basic spambots.

Comment: i would never show my email address on one of my sites, just use a contact form

Comment: How can you not show *any* email address on a site used by others?

Comment: by not displaying them, use contact forms then the email address are never seen.

Answer (score 0):

Add a captcha to the form can help a lot! Here is a good one: [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as simple as replacing parts of the email with descriptors...

```
foo[at]bar.com
foo@bar(dot)com
foo[at]bar[dot]com
```

...or just display emails as images. All depends on the level of effort you want to put into it, and what's most usable by you're users

Comment: Sounded like they wanted the email displayed in some places

Comment: just because something is wanted, doesn't mean its a good idea.

Comment: On a survey of about 10 prospective customers. They said that showing email on the site gave the site a bit of credibility.

Comment: Nothing wrong with showing emails. All depends on the context. I challenge you to find any business site that doesn't have at least one email address exposed

Comment: What is? You seriously must be trolling. Look at the "Contact Us" for *this* site

Comment: no I run a few dozen sites, no email addresses are ever shown. Bots have been searching the web for them for years; I don't want to make it easy for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can get rid of spamming.

Edit:
On my friend @ RamenChef's request ,putting the sample code here.

suppose you have a Password reset/Lost password page which is vulnerable to Spamming ,you can do something like this. Sample code below.

Try sending the forge request or try replaying the request.

**index.html - View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App secured from Spamming.</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                // Stop form from submitting normally
                event.preventDefault();
                /* Serialize the submitted form control values to be sent to the web server with the request */
                var formValues = $(this).serialize();
                // Send the form data using post
                $.post("test.php", formValues, function (data) {
                    // Display the returned data in browser
                    $("#result").html(data['message']);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $.post("test.php", function (data) {
                // Display the returned data in browser
                $('#token').val(data['token']);
                $("#result").html('<br>token generated --> '+data['token']);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p>Forgot password ?</p>
    <label>Email:
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" >
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
<footer style="text-align: center">Try clicking the Send button multiple times and the request is entertained only <b>ONCE for a session.</b></footer>

</html>
```

**test.php {server side}**

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "1";
$token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "1";

$data = array();


if ($email == 1 && $token == 1) {
    $serverToken = getToken(30);
    //generate token

    $_SESSION["current-token"] = $serverToken;
    $data['token'] = $serverToken;
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    if ($_SESSION["current-token"] == $token) {
        //lets process the valid request
        $data['message'] = 'Password reset link sent to ' . $email;
        $serverToken = getToken(30);

        //generate token
        $_SESSION["current-token"] = $serverToken;
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        $data['message'] = 'false client' . '  ----' . $_SESSION["current-token"];
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

}


function getToken($length)
{
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet .= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet .= "0123456789";
    $max = strlen($codeAlphabet); // edited

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0, $max)];
    }

    return $token;
}

function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max)
{
    $range = $max - $min;
    if ($range < 1) return $min; // not so random...
    $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
    $bytes = (int)($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
    $bits = (int)$log + 1; // length in bits
    $filter = (int)(1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
    do {
        $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
        $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
    } while ($rnd >= $range);
    return $min + $rnd;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13538477)

Comment: Okay. Lets share the sample code here as you have asked. :)

Answer (score -1):

Although not fool proof, another tactic is to use a hidden field in your form. Most bots will blindly fill it out. Check if it's filled out, if so, don't allow the form to submit.

```
        if ($_POST["bait"]!='') {
            header("location: http://www.google.com");
            exit;
               } else {
```